# Inheritance in Specflow features

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow

I am looking for a way to implement inheritance in specflow features. For e.g a base features class which has common scenarios which have to be tested.

3-4 derived features classes which inhert all the scenarios in the base class and add some of their own. Similarly the Binding class will also follow a inheritance structure. This is needed to test an ASP.NET MVC application which has a base controller (scenarios in base features class) and 4-5 implementations.

I can copy the features file for each derived controller class but this would lead to considerable duplication.

Is this possible in specflow, Or am I going down the wrong route? Please help. thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the right path to take (read as, I've never needed to do anything like this). For me any inheritance and re-use comes in the Step Definitions (or Binding) classes. But even so...

I don't know if you can simply do this using the tools available in SpecFlow - but you have the following option so far as I can see (this isn't a tested theory... I might test it later - but I figured this might offer you an idea...)

- The "code-behind" (designer-generate-code) for your Feature files are partial class implementations...
- ...so I guess you could create a "base" (generic) Feature file...
- ...then create a partial class file for each of your specific/implementation Feature files' code-behinds...
- ...each partial class will specify a base class which is the generated class name from the "base" Feature file code-behind.

Hopefully this helps a little.

EDIT:
Okay I've tested this theory... It would work as I've described above. I just created a new project with associated test/spec project, and did the above in the test/spec project. The test runner ran the base feature, and then ran the specific/implementation feature... which included the base feature again.

Have a go - it takes less than 5 minutes to knock up what I've suggested, and **see if the result fits your requirement.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This works perfectly just what I want. The only problem is that the inheritance feature class gets lost when the derived measure is updated, maybe because specflow regenerates the file. :( What I am trying to do is to reuse the same feature file for two different step definition classes which are derived from the same base step definition class. If I create two step definitions which are scoped to the same feature, it gives me an ambigious call :( it would be great if specflow took both matching step definitions and ran it

Comment: hi I was able to achieve this with Scenario Outlines. I passed in the values and had a abstract factory class which returned the instances based on a key in the scenario outline. I put all the common features in one feature file and will create new ones for special scenarios. But the main aim of not creating duplicate features is achieved using this technique.Thanks for your reply!!